# Solve for $p$ in this equation $\;2^{p−1}(2^p − 1) = X$.

Tags: prime-numbers, perfect-numbers

Solve for $p$ in this equation $2^{p−1}(2^p − 1) = X$.

This is a general formula for finding $X$ (an even perfect number), where $p$ is any prime number. I want to find $p$ when $X$ is given, so that I can say $X$ is an even perfect number if $p$ is prime.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $p = \lceil \log_4 2X \rceil$.

Comment: Note that $X = 2^{p-1}(2^p - 1)$ is *not automatically* a perfect number when $p$ is prime.  It should be restated as $X = 2^{p-1}(2^p - 1)$ is a perfect number when $2^p - 1$ is prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have
$$
2 2^{p-1}(2^p-1) = (2^p)^2 - 2^p = a^2-a = 2X,
$$ with $a = 2^p$-
hence
$$
a^2-a-2X = 0
$$ the quadratic formula, which has solutions
$$
a = \frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{1/4 + 2X}
$$ skip the negative solution and solve for $p$ in $2^p=a$
$$
p = \log_2(a) = \log_2\left (\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+2X} \right)
$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Set $Y=2^{p-1}$ then you equation is equivalent at $$Y(2Y-1)=X.$$